# How to determine body mass or weight?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, kinect, volume

I'm working on a Unity3D project to determine some personal properties of a body tracked by the Kinect (V2). Getting a persons length is no issue, but i'm struggeling to get someone weight.

I'm trying to calculate a body's volume (in M2) and multiply by an average BMI, but getting the volume seems hard.

I created a `point-cloud` by using a `particle-system` from the `depth-image`, but i can't wrap my head around the `depth-values`, which are crucial for determing a persons volume. I need to know the distance from a depth-pixel to the kinect-camera and calculate a volume from that somehow.

Has anyone done something similair or already has something to calculate a persons weight from the `kinectData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this is a kind of challenging question. in order to do this you will need to separate the body into shapes. For example head is like a globe and neck as a cylinder. so as you consider head like a globe then you can get the usual 'd' and calculate volume same as the cylinder.  For the lower body you can treat it as a box having height and width.There you can get the depth by getting the side view of the person. Anyway it is impossible you to calculate exact amount of volume with a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Separating the body into shapes seems difficult in the first place. For now i'm trying to calculate distance from the corresponding Joint to the actual z-depth of the pixel. Then i should try to add up all the values of each pixel and determine a 'weight' per pixel-depth, and add it all together.

Comment: now how you are going to calculate the weight per pixel I dont think it is possible at all with Kinect. This is a far more practical solution which you can even accept as the answer.

Comment: Yeah thats correct, i've accepted it as answer.
the problem with calculating a weight per pixel (treat every pixel as a box with volume), is that even when you're standing still, the amount of pixels differs alot. if i can somehow reduce that, i can get a pretty good estimate weight, but it will never be 100% or even 90% accurate.